# Syntax issue after temp table creation

Tags: temp-tables

Not sure why the following does not work (it's not recognizing the last select i.e., syntax error near SELECT).  Thanks.

```
    SELECT * INTO #temp FROM
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE')

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: What type of database is this? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, then you can't use `SELECT * INTO` because MySQL [doesn't support it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).

Instead, you could do this:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#temp` AS (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
);

SELECT * FROM `#temp`;
```

Also, if your table name has special characters in it you should quote it with backticks.

Comment: that didn't do it.  '#' indicates a temporary table with local scope.

Comment: @Guitoux If you're using MySQL, then that isn't your only problem. MySQL doesn't support `SELECT ... INTO` syntax.